# How to define a variable of global in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table of slider-groups like this and I'm on this page right now or in address. `http://localhost:8000/admin/slider-groups`

[image: sliderGroup]

When I click on this `+`, it redirects me to this address, `http://localhost:8000/admin/slider-groups/1/sliders` or in these tables

[image: sliders]

web.php

```
Route::resource('admin/slider-groups', 'Admin\SliderGroupController');
Route::prefix('admin/slider-groups/{sliderGroup}')->group(function(){
    Route::resource('admin/sliders', 'Admin\SliderController');
});
```

SliderGroupController.php

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $sliderGroups = SliderGroup::all();
    return view('admin.groups.index', compact('sliderGroups'));
}
```

admin.groups.index.blade.php

```
@foreach($sliderGroups as $sliderGroup)
    ...
    <a href="{{ route('admin::sliders.index',   $sliderGroup->id) }}" class="mr-1">
        <i class="la la-plus text-grey text-shadow-custom font-medium-4 font-weight-normal"></i>
    </a>
@endforeach
```

SliderController.php

```
public function edit($sliderGroupId,Slider $slider)
{
    return view('admin.sliders.edit', compact('slider', 'sliderGroupId'));
}
```

admin.sliders.edit.blade.php

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('admin::sliders.update', [$sliderGroupId,$slider->id ]) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    ...
```

SliderController.php

```
public function update(Request $request, Slider $slider, $sliderGroupId)
{
    dd($sliderGroupId);
}
```

I get this error.

> Argument 2 passed to Modules\Slider\Http\Controllers\Admin\SliderController::update() must be an instance of Modules\Slider\Entities\Slider, string given,

Comment: i think it should be {{ route('admin::sliders.update', [$slider->id,$sliderGroupId ]) }}

Comment: I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P9wV.png When I click submit

Comment: cache the routes and views and also config see if it helps.

Comment: I cached the routes and views and also config, but my problem did not solve yet. I get i.stack.imgur.com/8P9wV.png  again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update second parameter to the `route` function in **admin.sliders.edit.blade.php** as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('admin::sliders.update', ['slider' => $slider, 'sliderGroupId' => $sliderGroupId]) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    ...
```